# FB share not fetching proper image and data

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, share

I'm using fb share code for my product but unfortunately the image is taking from somewhere else in my website and the product heading is not fetching. I have used meta tags with data

```
<meta property="og:title" content=""/>
<meta property="og:description" content=""/>
<meta property="og:image" content=""/>
```

still issue remains same.

the code Im using is like this

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/share_button.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwebsitename.com%2Fcustomer%2Fproduct-details.php%3Fbusiness-id%3D108%26product-id%3D14&amp;layout=button_count" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

am behind this for last 5-6 hrs am stuck on this.

Comment: without a testlink it´s hard to help you. i assume "websitename.com" is not your domain.

Comment: http://onlinevyapari.com/customer/product-details.php?business-id=108&product-id=10

Comment: kindly see this link and try to share it is not fetching the proper image

Answer (score 1):

If Open Graph tags don´t work, put the link in the Facebook Debugger and refresh it: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

I have refreshed your link, looks like it is working now.

Comment: Thanks for the help but the image is not changing still same image for all product even after refreshing

Comment: works for me. keep in mind that stuff that is already shared on facebook will not change. but i tried sharing your link on facebook and the correct data showed up. of course you have to refresh every url, other links don´t just magically change if you refrehs one url in the debugger.